# Adding Checkbox to Ultimatelistctrl with append

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

So i have a ultimatelistctrl that looks like this:

```
    self.FileList=ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self.panel,size=(self.width,400),agwStyle=wx.LC_REPORT
                                       |ULC.ULC_USER_ROW_HEIGHT|ULC.ULC_SINGLE_SEL|ULC.ULC_BORDER_SELECT|ULC.ULC_AUTO_TOGGLE_CHILD)
    self.FileList.SetUserLineHeight(30)
    self.FileList.SetHeaderHeight(40)
    self.FileList.SetFont(self.ListText)
    #self.FileList.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_FOCUSED,self.OnItemSelect)

    #First Column
    info=ULC.UltimateListItem()
    info._mask=wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT|wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE|wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT|ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    info._image=[]
    info._format=0
    info._text="Select"
    info._kind=1
    self.FileList.InsertColumnInfo(0,info)
    self.FileList.SetColumnWidth(0,70)

    #Second Column
    info=ULC.UltimateListItem()
    info._mask=wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT|wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE|wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT|ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    info._image=[]
    info._format=0
    info._text="Name"
    self.FileList.InsertColumnInfo(1,info)
    self.FileList.SetColumnWidth(1,400)

    #Third Column
    info=ULC.UltimateListItem()
    info._mask=wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT|wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE|wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT|ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    info._image=[]
    info._format=0
    info._text="Database"
    self.FileList.InsertColumnInfo(2,info)
    self.FileList.SetColumnWidth(2,150)

    #fourth Column
    info=ULC.UltimateListItem()
    info._mask=wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT|wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE|wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT|ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    info._image=[]
    info._format=0
    info._text="Size"
    self.FileList.InsertColumnInfo(3,info)
    self.FileList.SetColumnWidth(3,150)

    #Fifth Column
    info=ULC.UltimateListItem()
    info._mask=wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT|wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE|wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT|ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    info._image=[]
    info._format=0
    info._text="Status"
    self.FileList.InsertColumnInfo(4,info)
    self.FileList.SetColumnWidth(4,110)
```

I want to now use append to add data to the list.

```
self.FileList.Append([wx.CheckBox(self.FileList,-1),listOfFiles[i],database,stringSize,""])
```

But i get the error

```
TypeError: argument of type 'CheckBox' is not iterable
```

I know i could create an item with

```
self.FileList.InsertStringItem(i,"",it_kind=1)
```

and then the checkbox is there and everything works. But i then have to add one line to insert every string and i also have to keep track of the item i just created.

But i whant to use the append function and i feel like im just calling the checkbox button wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a workaround so i can still use append. But i would still very much like it to know what to put inside the append to get a checkbox.

For now i just added after the append

```
self.FileList.SetItemKind(self.FileList.GetItemCount()-1,0,kind=1)
```

But its kinda not the real solution i looked after.